# How can I format a MVC3 WebGrid date column for local timezone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

My datetime values are stored as UTC in the database.  I want to display them in the local timezone using the standard MVC3 WebGrid control, but don't have a clue how to do that or where to look for the answer.

My current code looks like this:

```
grid.Column("TestDateTime", "Test Date/Time")
```

and I know THAT doesn't work!

Can somebody steer me in the right direction?  I do have access to the Telerik controls (free from the local user group) but have not tried them as it seems the more add-ons the more hassle (license fees, updates, keeping several dev environments in synch, etc).  If it's the only way to go I will do it, but would rather get Microsoft's standard tools to do the job.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like :

```
grid.Column("DueDate", "Due Date", format: (item) => String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", item.DueDate))
```

you can do pretty much anthing you need afer the format: marker

Comment: Thanks!! Here's what worked:    grid.Column("TestDateTime", "Test Date/Time", format: (item) => String.Format("{0:G}", item.TestDateTime.ToLocalTime()))

Comment: But this doesn't convert to local timezone. Instead, it converts to the server timezone. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Tom how can we Handle NULL values?